# How to disable automatic a switch when I enable another switch and how to fix ERROR Error: Invalid boolean:

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, switching

I have an error when I use switch: [demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=oaFogA) ERROR Error: Invalid boolean:

and I want to disable automatic a switch when I enable another switch.

For example, in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hDEU.png) I take active switch ON/OFF and Slider I want disable automatic. When I inactive switch ON/OFF I want and slider to in-disable automatic.

Can you share with me any idea how to implement this?

Comment: sounds like variable value is not `boolean` or way for declaration variable is not correct

Comment: Yes I know that but I don't understand in which part

Answer (score 1):

You can assign template variables to both the switches(`switch` and `switch2` as given in the example code below) and then check for `switch2.checked` to set the `switch.isEnabled` on the `(checkedChange)` of `switch2`.

Give this a try:

```
<Switch 
  formControlName="wireless" 
  style="text-align: center" 
  #switch 
  class="m-15" 
  row="1" 
  col="1" 
  (checkedChange)="onFirstCheckedWireless($event)">
</Switch>

<Switch 
  #switch2 
  formControlName="wireless1" 
  style="text-align: center" 
  class="m-15" 
  row="1" 
  col="2" 
  (checkedChange)="switch.isEnabled = !switch2.checked">
</Switch>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Playground Link**](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Jg0fcN) for your ref.